# select one to many relation in core data fetch don't work

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

[image]

i used this code to select all products that related to specific category but it doesn't work ,, what is the correct predicate that i can use to get all products related to this category

NOTE:
i get the categories list from server alone and insert them ,, and then get products list from server and inserting them ,, but i figured out now that the product don't know his category ,, i'm using restkit library to parse and insert in the database ,, so how i can tell the products that the category ,, the restkit do all the work automatically

how to set to the product list thet i get from server their category ?

```
  //--fetching inserted Results from core data
    // Getting products
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"productId" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor , nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
//    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category = %@ ",tempCategoryHolder];
//    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate] ;


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    fetchedObjectsProducts = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Why is the predicate commented out? How did it not work? What is `tempCategoryHolder`? What do you get if you log `tempCategoryHolder.products`?

Comment: no , i just commented it because the code isn't work well

Comment: Show your mappings. You need to do a foreign key mapping connection...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, assuming tempCategoryHolder holds a categoryId:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.categoryId = %@", tempCategoryHolder];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"productId" ascending:YES]];
NSArray *fetchedObjectsProducts = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Otherwise update the predicate to refer to category object, or different category attribute.

Comment: i get the categories list from server alone and insert them ,, and then get products list from server and inserting them ,, but i figured out now that the product don't know his category ,, i'm using restkit library to parse and insert in the database ,, so how i can tell the products that the category ,, the restkit do all the work automatically

Comment: how to set to the product list thet i get from server their category ?

Comment: I don't work with RestKit, therefore I don't know how it stores the fetched data into Core Data. Normally you get JSON or XML, parse the array or directory and once you hold the objects you simply insertNewObjectForEntityForName and set its attributes. They key is to set the Category object on the Product along with other Product attributes. Paste the storing and saving code for review.

Comment: so what do you think about restkit ,, is it better to work manually with every thing ??

Comment: It looks good and I know it's popular for interacting with web service. I just did not have a need yet. You need to dig into why the relationship is not set.